# How to create model object in bagging?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I tried creating a function for Ensemble of Ensemble modelling:

```
library(foreach)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(10)
Y<-round(runif(1000))
x1<-c(1:1000)*runif(1000,min=0,max=2)
x2<-c(1:1000)*runif(1000,min=0,max=2)
x3<-c(1:1000)*runif(1000,min=0,max=2)
all_data<-data.frame(Y,x1,x2,x3)
bagging = function(dataFile, length_divisor = 4, iterations = 100)
{
    fit = list()
    predictions = foreach(m = 1 : iterations, .combine = cbind) %do% 
    {
        dataFile$Y = as.factor(dataFile$Y)
        rf_fit = randomForest(Y ~ ., data = dataFile, ntree = 100)
        fit[[m]] = rf_fit
        rf_fit$votes[,2]
    }
    rowMeans(predictions)
    return(list(formula = as.formula("Y ~ ."), trees = fit, ntree = 100, class = dataFile$Y, votes = predictions))
}
final_model = bagging(all_data)
predict(final_model, TestData) # It says predict doesn't support final_model object
# Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"
```

It says -

> Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list".

I need the above function `bagging` to return an aggregated model object so that I can predict on new data set.

Comment: If you are attempting to make a new "bagging" function and want it returning a value that will have its own predict method, then you need to assign a class values returned by it and also create a `predict.thatclass`-function to process the results. There really is no default predict function. There are only class-specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bagging` function just returns an arbitrary list. Predict looks to the class of the first parameter to know "the right thing" to do. I assume you want to predict from the randomForest objects stored inside the list? You can loop over your list with `Map()`. For example

```
Map(function(x) predict(x, TestData), final_model$trees)
```

(untested since you didn't seem to provide `TestData`)

Comment: Let `TestData = all_data` and tried doing the `Map()`. It returns a list with 100 items each having the votes for the 1000 rows. But in general bagging returns you a single model object right (which is an aggregated result of 100 models)? I need such result.

Comment: You haven't defined bagging at all so it's unclear what you think this function should do big you have questions about statistical models, you should ask at [stats.se], otherwise be more precise about what your programming question is.

Comment: I am creating a function called `bagging()` which is similar to `glm()` or `randomForest()`. It is like I am creating my own model (Say, Bagging of Random Forest models). Like `randomForest()` or `glm()` I need my function to return a model object which can be passed as a parameter to `predict()` function. Let me give you an example `randomForest()` returns a list of trees, votes, classes..etc. but, it is a model object (of class randomForest) right ? I need my `bagging()` function also to be working in the same way.